# Comparison between rings and groups Question

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Show by example, that for nonzero (fixed) elements a & b in a ring, the equation ax=b can have more than one solution. How does this compare to groups? 
Can someone help me compare rings to groups?

Comment: $ax=b$ have one unique solution in a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ (or any other field); can you give an example of
$$
AX=B
$$
having infinite solutions?

Comment: Good hint: and if you get stuck sprgrl11, try the case with $B=0$ since you already know $X=0$ is an easy solution!

Answer (score 1):

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n$  the equation $ax=b$   has  $d=(a,n)$ solutions.